# Polarion ALM JAVA SDK API WorkItem get Type representation

Tags: java, sdk, alm, polarion

I have a question regarding the `Polarion JAVA API SDK`.

I can get the `workItem` using:

```
WorkItem wi = trackerService.getWorkItem(workItemURL);
```

Then I get the type:

```
EnumOptionId type = wi.getType();
```

Now how can I get the Type representation text? 
And can I get the Icon of the `WorkItem` using API?
Also is there a way to get all `WorkItem` Types from Polarion?

Answer (score 1):

For your tasks, the EnumOptionId object has the following methods(:

```
.getId()       // returns the Id of this type
.getName()     // returns the human readable name of this type
.getProperty(IEnumOption.PROPERTY_KEY_ICON_URL)   // returns the URL of the Icon of this type
```

Note that these methods are available also for other enumeration types, like priority, status or user defined enums.

Answer (score 0):

for rendering Work Items, you might consider using the rendering API.

You could use something like this in Velocity (You can use it in script blocks in report pages):

```
## Get Project Id
#set($projectId = $page.fields().project().projectId())

## Get Work Items with new API
#set($renderWIs = $transaction.workItems().search().query("type:systemrequirement AND project.id:$projectId"))

## Render Work Items
#foreach($WI in $renderWIs)
    $WI.render().withLinks()<br>
#end
```

Check out this blog post explaing the difference: https://polarion.code.blog/2020/06/16/rendering-vs-open-api/

Answer (score 0):

After getting EnumOptionId from WorkItem.

for type name - `type.getName();`

for icon url - `type.getProperty("iconURL")`

for other requirements, you can refer to the following image.
[image]
[ITypeOpt](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/tracker/model/ITypeOpt.html)

[Constant Values](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.polarion.platform.persistence.IEnumOption.PROPERTY_KEY_ICON_URL)